# concept using helper class

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae, c++-concepts

In order to be able to write stuff like `cout << vec` for iterable types like `vector<int> vec;`, I wanted to define `operator<<(osteam&, const T&)` for iterable `T` only. My first shot was

```cpp
template<class T> using extract_iterator_t = typename T::iterator;
template<class T> concept iterable = requires { typename extract_iterator_t<T>; };

template<iterable T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const T& seq) {
  for(const auto& i: seq) os << i << ',';
  return os;
}
```

but that misses iterable things like `int*`, so I replaced the first line by

```cpp
template<class T> struct extract_iterator { using type = T::iterator; };
template<class T> struct extract_iterator<T*> { using type = T*; };
template<class T> struct extract_iterator<T[]> { using type = T*; };
template<class T> using extract_iterator_t = typename extract_iterator<T>::type;
```

However, now g++-11.1 refuses to compile this, saying

```
error: 'char' is not a class, struct, or union type
```

because it tries to use my custom `operator<<` for the `<<','` part, rightfully complaining about a substitution failure. However, I always thought **S**ubstitution **F**ailure **I**s **N**ot **A**n **E**rror, so why would g++ insist on using my custom `operator<<` for `<<','`?
Here's the godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/jejexE18h

Edit: everyone pointing out ranges is correct that they are the right tool to use for this, but this example was just to illustrate a problem I have with a construct similar but not equal to ranges - I thought I'd present a minimum breaking example instead of telling a long introductory story which boils down to the same problem.

Comment: Don't you just mean `std::ranges::range`? Not "is it an iterator" but "is it a range".

Comment: The interesting part is that some iterators like `directory_iterator` and `recursive_directory_iterator` are actually ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in your primary definition:

```cpp
template <class T> struct extract_iterator { using type = T::iterator; };
```

the failure that happens when we try to do `T::iterator` is outside of the immediate context of the substitution, so it is not SFINAE-friendly.

You could fix this by adding the right constraint:

```cpp
template<class T> struct extract_iterator;
template<class T> requires requires { typename T::iterator; }
struct extract_iterator<T> { using type = T::iterator; };
```

---

But this whole approach is wrong anyway. `T*` isn't *iterable*, it's an *iterator*. And C++20 already comes with the tool you need for this job: Ranges:

```cpp
template <std::ranges::range R>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, R&& seq);
```

Note that this is problematic anyway for other reasons, and you should instead just use `fmt` which comes with direct support for [formatting ranges](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#ranges-api) in a proper way.

Comment: I've never heard of "SFINAE-friendlyness" or SFINAE being restricted to "the immediate context" - is there some form of documentation as to what that means exactly?